# cancan with one role per user: defining roles cumulatively through a series of conditional statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using cancan with one role per user. The roles are integers instead of strings. My  ability.rb is organized like this:

```
def initialize(user, session)
    if user.role.to_i == 9
        can :create, [Resource1, Resource2, Resource3]
        can :update, [Resource1, Resource2, Resource3]
    elsif user.role.to_i == 8
        can :create, [Resource1, Resource2]
        can :update, [Resource1, Resource2]
    else
        can :create, Resource1
        can :update, Resource1
    end
end
```

In reality there are 7 roles instead of 3 and the file is much more complex. Could the file be rewritten like this instead so a role can be defined cumulatively through the conditional statements?

```
def initialize(user, session)
    if user.role.to_i >= 9
        can :create, Resource3
        can :update, Resource3
    end
    if user.role.to_i >= 8
        can :create, Resource2
        can :update, Resource2
    end
    can :create, Resource1
    can :update, Resource1
end
```

I'd like to know if this EXACT structure with the conditional statements would work before i rewrite the entire file. Thanks.

Comment: Flaw: `user.role.to_i`. I don't like comparing integers by its string. But just a personal opinion.

Comment: +1 for a good call. I adopted your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (except for the comparison). Look [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/ability.rb#L124), it adds the rule.

```
def can(action = nil, subject = nil, conditions = nil, &block)
  rules << Rule.new(true, action, subject, conditions, block)
end
```

**Edit:** In case it may be useful.

```
def initialize(user, session)
  resources = [Resource1]
  resources << Resource2 if user.role.to_i >= 8
  resources << Resource2 if user.role.to_i >= 9
  can :create, resources
  can :update, resources
end
```

**Edit 2:**

### What does the first part mean?

In first place, sorry for pasting the wrong chunk of code. Then, you can see you are adding a new rule whose subject is the one you passed to `can`. In `Rule` [initializer](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/rule.rb#L13), you can see the line:

```
@subjects = [subject].flatten
```

that means that if you had an array you still have that array (that's what `flatten` is for), but if you had only one resource you get a one-item array. You can dig more in the code and you will notice than a rule with one resource behaves as a rule with only one.

Then this rule is added to `rules` without replacing any other.

Hope is clear now.

Comment: +1 for the edit... very useful. I'm not yet understanding how the first part of your answer applies yet.

Comment: So, @Serabe, i modified the last sentence of the question to get at what i was driving at. I'm not sure if the comparison you are referring to is the conditional statements.